# How to create a Button, that blinks after clicked?

Tags: android, button, view, background

So far I learned how animations work and how to set the background of a button according to its state as described [here](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56).

Well, I defined an animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<alpha 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0"  
    android:duration="50" 
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="6"/>
```

I start the animation in the onClick(View v) method. The problem now is, that the actual click action gets processed before the animation finishes. I know I could use an AnimationListener, but this would not look very nice to me since I'd have to call the actual click processes within the AnimationListener then.

Does anyone know a more skilful way to let a button blink after it gets clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Selector tag like Follows: Create a New xml file and place it in your drawable folder and name it as shadow_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ask_footer"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/askfooter_hover" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ask_footer" />
</selector>
```

And then go to that xml in which your Button is declared: And write one attribute in Button

`android:background="@drawable/shadow_color"` 
and you are done.

Mark the answer if you find it usefull..

Comment: So in your code "ask_footer" is my specific button background? This selector does only change the background of the button once, right? But I want the background to change multiple times. Like I declared in my animation xml.

Comment: I used this to have a background color on a text view change when clicked. Simply use `android:drawable="@color/white"` or whatever color you want on pressed or not pressed states. I wanted to show a click happened when the new intent took a while to start.

Answer (score 0):

## Define the `onclick` for the button

```
button1.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick (View v){ calcular(1,v); }
    }
);
```

## Make your button blink

This makes the images defined in the XML alternate between each other.

```
    public void calcular(final int p,final View v){
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
        mp.start();
        //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dia1btn_stl2);
        final TransitionDrawable transition1 = 
                 (TransitionDrawable) v.getBackground();
        Handler blinkHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:

                    transition1.startTransition(70);

                        break;
                case 1:
                    transition1.resetTransition();
                    break;

                }
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };


    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
         if(i % 2 == 0){
             msg.what = 0;
         }
        else{
            msg.what=1;
        }

        blinkHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, i*100);
    }

        /*mCurrentSeries.clear();
        if(calcularctrl == 0){
            calcularctrl = 1;
            dtdodo = new DownloadImageTask(this , p , codacaovalue);
            dtdodo.execute("wwwkjhdijdh");
        }*/

        Handler handler2 = new Handler(); 
        handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() { 
                  //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dia1btn_stl2); 
                mCurrentSeries.clear();
                if(calcularctrl == 0){
                    calcularctrl = 1;
                    dtdodo = new DownloadImageTask(outer() , p , codacaovalue);
                    dtdodo.execute("wwwkjhdijdh");
                }
                try {
                    this.finalize();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
             public acoesdetalhes outer(){
                 return acoesdetalhes.this;
             }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

## The XML of the button background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mes1btn_stl2" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mes1btn_prssd2" />
</transition>
```

This code provided in part by user Alin.

Comment: Thanks wes , the code is more easy to understand now. I forgot to clear the code so I will give a brief . The class DownloadImageTask is a AsyncTask who receive a Context as a parameter which is  returned from outer() the return is acoesdetalhes the Activity , the main class.The handler2 is used to call a function after the blink of the button.